# Dijkstra's Shortest Path Algo for Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm having a lot of trouble implementing dijkstras algo into my unity game.

I have exactly 1980 nodes in my map and depending on what building you place in each of those nodes whether it be a road/blockade/citycentre/house etc depends on if it is traversable or not and depends on the weight if it is traversable.

```
Road weight = 1
Grassland weight = 2
Forest weight = 3
Blockade weight = 4
All other nodes = not traversable OR 5000+
```

I want the algo to only traverse horizontally and vertically, no diagonals included in the path and I want it to find my the SHORTEST path, hence dijkstras. I know dijkstras is known to be something you implement if you have a time complexity constraint but in my case it doesn't matter if it takes 0.1ms or 3s.

Every dijkstras algo i've found on the internet using C# doesn't include a way to dynamically generate a graph and I think this is where i'm having all my issues. All of the examples i've found have the logic, but manually set a adjacency list or something of the sort, which doesn't really work for me as each player in my game will have the freedom to choose which building goes on what node so the number of traversable nodes will be dynamic.

Any suggestions or questions welcome, Struggling rn.

Cheers, GameDevDumbo.

Comment: Hi hi, welcome! Add the code that you already have to the question so we can begin to comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is on how to represent a 2D map as a graph, lets start by introducing an interface for a graph, and lets make it generic just because:

```
public interface IGraph<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    IEnumerable<(T Node, double cost)> GetNeighbors(T node);
}
```

I.e. given some arbitrary node we return all the neighboring nodes, with the associated costs. Using an interface would let us keep the same algorithm implementation with different kinds of graph representations.

We can then write a simple class that implements this, using a multidimensional array to describe our map. Using an enum to describe our map-values, and a multidimensional array to describe the map itself:

```
public class MapGraph : IGraph<Point>
{
    public enum MapNodeType
    {
        Road ,
        Grassland ,
        Forest ,
        Blockade 
    }
    private readonly MapNodeType[,] map;

    public MapGraph(MapNodeType[,] map) => this.map = map;

    private static readonly Size[] OffsetsFourConnected = new Size[]
    {
        // Four connected
        new Size(0, 1),
        new Size(1, 0),
        new Size(0, -1),
        new Size(-1, 0)
    };
    public IEnumerable<(Point Node, double cost)> GetNeighbors(Point node)
    {
        foreach (var offset in OffsetsFourConnected)
        {
            var newNode = node + offset;
            // Check that the new node is within the bounds
            if (((uint) newNode.X) < map.GetLength(0) &&
                ((uint) newNode.Y) < map.GetLength(1))
            {
                switch (map[newNode.X, newNode.Y])
                {
                    case MapNodeType.Road: yield return (newNode,1); break;
                    case MapNodeType.Grassland: yield return (newNode, 2); break;
                    case MapNodeType.Forest: yield return (newNode, 3); break;
                    case MapNodeType.Blockade: yield return (newNode, 4); break;
                    default: break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is not very optimized. Iterator blocks are convenient, but not ideal for high performance. You would typically also use A* for shortest path if performance was of a concern. It uses system.Drawing.Point for coordinates, but any integer point type will do.

You will also need some method of loading the map, from a bitmap or some other representation, but the question does not describe the map format, so it is a bit pointless to guess.